How to define NVARCHAR in Ktor with Exposed ORM + SQL Server
I am using Exposed ORM with Ktor along with a SQL Server database. I am trying to save Arabic text to a database column. Since Exposed has no nvarchar implementation, I tried different tweaks to solve this issue but, without success.
Based on this: I tried to modify the JDBC connection string and append character encoding UTF-16 but it had no effect.
jdbc:sqlserver://DESKTOP;databaseName=MyDb;integratedSecurity=true;encrypt=false;characterEncoding=utf8&useUnicode=true;"


Based on this from Microsoft documentation, I was able to find the following solution when needing to support the use of different languages using Exposed ORM.
val arabicTextColumn= registerColumn<String>("arabicTextColumn", TextColumnType(collate = "utf16_general_ci"))

In the link, you can find a list of all languages and encodings supported.
